# Type to navigate and open anything on screen by using keyboard ? Similar to shortcatapp.com

Tags: windows, mouse, keyboard-navigation

Is there a way to let me type and navigate to anywhere on the screen ? It's definitely faster than searching for the text on the screen.

On Mac, I knew there's such app: http://shortcatapp.com/ . Any similar product for Windows user (Windows 7/8) ?

Comment: which version of windows are you talking about.

Comment: also i don't think there is anything that does this that's installed into windows already. which would be pushing into the product recommendation area.

Comment: @Sickest : I would say Windows 7/8 (ideally Windows Server 2008/2012 as well). Anyway 3rd party apps are totally acceptable - even paid app like shortcatapp.com